# Expand Div As Percentage of Height on Hover?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap and trying to do a little simple css animation on hover, expanding the element to highlight it.

```
.text-block {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: .1s;
  margin: 1em;
}

.text-block:hover {
  margin: 0em;
  transition: .1s;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

This almost looks right, as the element appears to be expanded since the margin is animated away, but it moves up the page so it appears only 3 sides of the element grow.

Is it possible to set the height on hover to the non-hover height+2em to make it appear to grow 1em in all directions within CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Change margin to padding. Margin adds blank space outside of your element. Padding should give you the effect you want :D